# ADF - Multiple Lookup Activities

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I am using 2 lookup activities.

First look up Activity gives the out put like

```
 `"count": 20,
    "value": [
{
"SCHEMA_NAME": "DM","TABLE_NAME": "'MD_ASSET"},
        {
"SCHEMA_NAME":"DM","TABLE_NAME": "'MD_ASSET_SHARD'"}`
```

I am using Second Lookup Activity in which i have to use the list of schema names and table names in the query used in my second lookup activity:

```
`@concat('Select 
    distinct s.name as SchemaName, object_name(i.object_id) AS TableName,
    i.name AS IndexName
    FROM sys.indexes AS i
    JOIN sys.dm_db_column_store_row_group_physical_stats AS CSRowGroups
    WHERE object_name(i.object_id)  IN (','',activity('ACT_LKP_OBJECT_AAS').output.value[0] 
    ['TABLE_NAME'],'',' ) AND  (state_desc= ''OPEN'' and total_rows>1000))  and state_desc 
    <>''TOMBSTONE''')`
```

if you see above highlighted text am only able to access one element in from my previous look activity but i need to use the complete array returned.

How can i do that so i use the complete list in the sql query used in the second lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the source database for the Lookup is the same as the next one?  In that case, you would be much much better off organising this into a single stored procedure which was self-contained and call a single Stored Proc activity to run.

Core ADF is not going to allow you do to this without using a For Each activity and Append activity which you don't really need.

Use a Stored Proc or Script activity:

[image]